# Using robot_localization navsat_transform_node to fuse IMU and GPS measurements from a drone

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm looking throuh the robot_localization package and I'm a bit confused on how to use the navsat_transform node to fuse measurements coming from a drone.

I have three topics:

```
dji_odom for odometry.
dji_imu for Imu data.
dji_gps for gps data.
```

which according to the tutorial are the sample inputs. My issue is I'm not quite sure where these inputs are meant to be in the package.
I'm using the sample `dual_ekf_navsat_example` file which looks like:

```
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml" />

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_odom" clear_params="true"/>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

Initally, I thought this was meant to be added in the dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml. Mine looks like this:

```
ekf_se_odom:
  frequency: 50
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: m100/base_link
  world_frame: odom

  odom0: dji_odom
  odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true, true, true]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  imu0: dji_imu
  imu0_config: [true, true, true,
                true,  true,  true,
                true, true, true,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false
   //covariances removed for brevity


ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: false
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map

  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: map

  odom0: dji_odom
  odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true,  true,  true,
                 true, true, true,
                 true, true, true]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  odom1: dji_gps
  odom1_config: [true,  true,  true,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom1_queue_size: 10
  odom1_nodelay: true
  odom1_differential: false
  odom1_relative: false

  imu0: dji_imu
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: // removed for brevity

  initial_estimate_covariance: //removed for brevity

navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 3.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.013945181  # For lat/long 55.944831, -3.186998
  yaw_offset: 0  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
  zero_altitude: false
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
```

But I get the following error: `Client [/ekf_se_map] wants topic to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7], but our version has [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix/2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48]. Dropping connection.`  which has to do with `odom1` on `ekf_se_map` which makes sense I guess. My question is where do you add the GPS data to fuse into the package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307050/using-robot_localization-navsat_transform_node-to-fuse-imu-and-gps-measurements-from-a-drone/) by [marinePhD](https://answers.ros.org/users/36566/marinephd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My question is where do you add the
> GPS data to fuse into the package?

In your launch file you need to remap your GPS fix topic to the input of the navsat transform.

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>

    <remap from "/gps/fix" to "your GPS output topic here" /> 

  </node>
```

Was that your question?

You'll also need to remap your IMU topic. The navsat node requires all three.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0